# How to use methods which are not in interface with interface i = new class();

Tags: java, oop

I am only able to access methods/vars of m1/m2 which are in the interface Measurable how do i access other methods and vars?

How is it possible to use the getLength() AND getBreadth()/getRadius() method of m1/m2 object in the getArea() method? Thanks in Advance!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Circle c = new Circle(10);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10,5);

        addArea(c, r);

        Measurable Rec = new Rectangle(10, 5);
        Measurable Cir = new Circle(10);

        addArea(Rec, Cir);
    }

    public static void addArea(Measurable m1, Measurable m2){
        String m1s = null,m2s = null;

        if(m1 instanceof Rectangle){
            m1s="Rectangle";
        }
        else if(m1 instanceof Circle){
            m1s="Circle";
        }

        if(m2 instanceof Circle){
            m2s="Circle";
        }
        else if(m2 instanceof Rectangle){
            m2s="Rectangle";
        }

        System.out.println("Area of "+m1s+" and "+m2s+" is "+(m1.getArea()+m2.getArea())+"\n");
    }

}

interface Measurable{
    double PI = 3.14;
    public double getPerimeter();
    public double getArea();
}

class Rectangle implements Measurable{

    public double breadth, length;

    public Rectangle(int breadth, int length){
        this.breadth = breadth;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*(breadth+length);
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return length*breadth;
    }

    public double getLength(){
        return length;
    }

    public double getBreadth(){
        return breadth;
    }

}

class Circle implements Measurable{

    public double radius;

    public Circle(int radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*PI*radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return PI*radius*radius;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code of the classes that implement the **Measurable** interface.

Comment: Just use casting . `((Circle)m3).getLength()` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast your objects, do that in your if blocs and assign the value to a `String` object. The reference of the interface can not make a call to a method written in one class that implements it.

---

### Solution

E.g for `getLength()` and `m1`

```
String m1Length = null;
if(m1 instanceof Rectangle){
    m1s="Rectangle";
    m1Length = ((Rectangle)m1).getLength());
}
else if(m1 instanceof Circle){
    m1s="Circle";
    m1Length = ((Circle)m1).getLength());
}
```

Apply this logic to the rest of the code and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is this called upcasting or downcasting?

Comment: @hp7 You're welcome :) This is called [Downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting)